# Prove that 5^n = o(n!)

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

Please help me providing a direction on how to prove this. I can prove by randomly finding value of n that makes n! greater than 5^n. But can someone help me prove mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use induction.

If `5^n < n!` and `5 <= n+1`, then `5^(n+1) == 5 * 5^n < (n+1) * n! == (n+1)!`.

Comment: How we can assume 5 <= n+1. n can be 1 or 2 or 3. Also if we assume 5 <= n+1 then 5^n will be <= n!. But we want to prove 5^n < n!

Comment: It's not true for `n<4` anyway.  Start with whatever value you randomly find that does make `n! > 5^n`.  Asymptotic analysis means you get to choose any starting value you want!

Answer (score -1):

```
5^n = o(n!) <=> if n close to ∞ limit 5^n/n! close to 0
```

prove:

```
set An = 5^n/n!, when n > 10, An = 5^n/n! < 1/(n-5)!
for An > 0 and limit 1/(n-5)! close to 0, then 0 <= limit An <= limit 1/(n-5)! <= 0
so limit 5^n/n! close to 0, and 5^n = o(n!)
```